# Hibernate Не создается таблица в базе

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь разобраться с Hibernate и создать простенькую таблицу в БД mysql. Но таблица не хочет создаваться и не могу разобраться почему.
Что выдает консоль:

```
янв 28, 2018 12:39:32 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
янв 28, 2018 12:39:32 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
янв 28, 2018 12:39:33 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
янв 28, 2018 12:39:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
янв 28, 2018 12:39:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate]
янв 28, 2018 12:39:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
янв 28, 2018 12:39:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
янв 28, 2018 12:39:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
янв 28, 2018 12:39:35 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
янв 28, 2018 12:39:36 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.7.Final
янв 28, 2018 12:39:36 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@1d730606'
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password" />
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="User" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;


    private int age;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String lastname;
```

Comment: hibernate.properties not found - вам уже написали о вашей проблеме, не найден конфигурационный файл хибернейта

Comment: у вас класс User без пакета?

Comment: а еще поменяйте свойства конфигурации driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?useSSL=false dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect И версию драйвера берите 5.1.43. Можете, конечно, пробовать запускать и с другими настройками, но последняя бд на мускуле, которую я запускал с хибером и спрингом работает до сих пор именно с такими настройками